# How do I use the event listener? I have tried to use it but it is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/g6L233by/4/) is my code. I'm trying to make it work but I can't. I have tried the things on here but it hasn't changed anything. The event listener is unresponsive.

```
c1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
c2.drawImage(img2, posx, posy)

function move(key) {
    keyy = event.keyCode;
    switch (keyy) {
        case 38:
            posy -= 10;
            break;
        case 40:
            posy += 10;
            break;
        case 37:
            posx -= 10;
            break;
        case 39:
            posx += 10;
            break;
    }
    c1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    c2.drawImage(img2, posx, posy)
}
div.addEventListener("keydown", move(event.keyCode));
```

Comment: simply put div.addEventListener("keydown", move) ; you're calling the move function with the brackets on.

Comment: tried that, didn't work.
edit:
it did work, js fiddle was acting stubborn

Comment: also define move as move(event)

Comment: after years of dealing with stonewalls and dragged out tutorials, i can finally, make something move!!!!!!!!! for that you have my thanks

Comment: if it helped you..pls accept my ans. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to :

change

```
function move(key){
```

to

```
function move(event){
```

and

```
div.addEventListener("keydown", move(event.keyCode));
```

to

```
div.addEventListener("keydown", move);
```